# Route advertisement and FIB programming

Tags: bgp, networking, ip-forwarding-table

Que1. Assuming `bgp` is running on a network device, will the route advertisement and FIB programming(basically populating entries in hardware) occur in `parallel`?
Or does it occur sequentially, meaning, first the FIB is programmed and then the routes are advertised?

Que2. Ideally if a network device advertise the routes before FIB programming, this will lead to traffic blackholing/traffic getting dropped. Is that correct understanding?

Que3. How about `withdraw` routes ?

Comment: BGP only advertises prefixes that are already in the routing table, it does not advertise any to which it does not already have a route.

Comment: @RonMaupin, if a route exists in routing table, is it confirmed for sure that the FIB has already been programmed ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. You seem to think there is a difference. The FIB is the routing table that a router uses to route packets.

Comment: apologies for not making myself clear; i intend to understand that if FIB is updated , could there still be the case that hardware is not yet programmed ?

Comment: I really do not understand. What hardware, and what programming? A router routes packets based on what is in the routing table (FIB), and if there is no matching prefix in the routing table, a packet is dropped. BGP will only advertise prefixes that already exist in the routing table; you cannot tell BGP to advertise a prefix unless it exactly matches a routing table entry, and that seems to be the essence of your question..

Comment: Search for BGP state machines. Logically I think the route should be already in FIB before it is advertised to other neighbors, to prevent a black hole.

Comment: A reminder that BGP is optimized to handle hundreds of thousands of routes rather than rapid convergence. This is different than IGPs (ex. OSPF) which converge quickly but cannot handle as many routes. You seem very concerned about BGP packet loss due to an update being propagated to another router (and route/fib processing there) before FIB installation on the local router. I’d be more concerned with why there was an update in the first place.  It will take several minutes for the update to get through the Internet, and if you issue too many updates for the same route you will get dampened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a certain point, the answer is "that depends on the implementation". However, it's *very likely* that the forwarding table is updated *as soon as possible*, while BGP updates have a slightly lower priority and are processed *afterwards*. As you've described, it doesn't make sense to advertise a route that's not working yet.

Removing routes follows the same logic - an obsolete route is removed from the FIB before a BGP update can be sent out and processed by the other peers. In extreme, that could lead to a temporary routing loop.